# Cannot build JXBrowser jar with v6.18+

Tags: java, maven, jxbrowser

I am getting some errors that had been fixed according to the 6.18 release notes and was hoping to bump the dependency version to fix the issue, but when I `mvn install` the project now, I get a build error

`Classes found in the wrong directory: {META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/swing/internal/AWTHelper$1.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.AWTHelper$1, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/swing/internal/NativeLinux.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.NativeLinux, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/javafx/internal/NativeMac.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.internal.NativeMac, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/javafx/internal/dialogs/ColorDialog.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.internal.dialogs.ColorDialog, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/internal/JavaVersion.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.JavaVersion, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/swing/internal/AWTHelper.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.AWTHelper, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/swing/internal/Native.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.Native, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/internal/X509CertificateFactory.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.X509CertificateFactory, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/swing/internal/AWTHelper$InstanceHolder.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.internal.AWTHelper$InstanceHolder, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/javafx/internal/Native.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.internal.Native, META-INF/versions/9/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/internal/OS.class=com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.OS}`

I have cleared my maven cache and tried versions 6.18-6.20 but I can only build with 6.17 and below.  My license file claims to work for versions 6.X, so I would assume that is not the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the version 6.18, JxBrowser provides multi-release jars, so it is able to work with both Java 8 and Java 9. And it seems that the maven used to build the application does not support the MR-JAR's, so it generates a build error. So you need to upgrade Maven version.